# Multiple buttons to perform actions using 1 php file

Tags: php, button, isset

I am trying to use multiple buttons in which each perform a different action on a table. For example if you click the 'Add to Sold' button, any checkbox that is selected will have an action performed on it (their status is changed to sold). I have the action php ready to go... however I am unsure how to put it all together so I can have 1 table with 4 different buttons.
For right now I am just trying to echo out a statement that will show me that it is working.

Here are the buttons:

```
 <form action="/includes/tester.php" method="POST">

     <button class="button2" type="submit" value="runlist" name="runlist"><i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o" style="color:white; font-size:20px; padding:0px"></i> Add to Runlist</button>
     <button class="button2" type="submit" value="sold" name="sold"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" style="color:white; font-size:20px; padding:0px"></i> Add to Sold</button>
     <button class="button2" type="submit" value="shop" name="shop"><i class="fa fa-wrench" style="color:white; font-size:20px; padding:0px"></i> Add to Shop</button>
     <button class="button2" type="submit" value="delete" name="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color:white; font-size:20px; padding:0px"></i> Delete</button>

 </form>
```

Once selected the php document will run called tester.php. Here is the code that I am trying to use for the php to understand which button is pressed.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['runlist'])){
    echo 'Runlist pressed';
}
else if (isset($_POST['sold'])){
    echo 'sold pressed';
}
else if (isset($_POST['shop'])){
    echo 'shop pressed';
}
else if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
    echo 'delete pressed';
}

}
?>
```

Of course I am misunderstanding something because it only works when I have only 1 if statement. Please help, thank you for your time.

Comment: else if should be elseif

Comment: @Grant — No. [Note that elseif and else if will only be considered exactly the same when using curly brackets as in the above example](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: Andrew, what have you tried to debug this problem?

Comment: When I run this code, it errors with *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file in /Users/XXXXX/tmp/jkfdjfkdjk/index.php on line 24*. If I remove the `}` on the penultimate line, it works perfectly. Voting to close as off-topic because the only issue I can find is caused by a typo.

Comment: Thank you Quintin! It works!